# Should I go to engineering graduate school right after undergrad or after a few years of work experience?

Tags: graduate-school, industry

I've heard a few pros and cons about each.

If you go right away, you'll just get it out of the way.

If you wait to go, you'll learn way more and understand what's useful to focus on.

On the other hand, if you've been earning money, it will be harder to go back to living on a graduate student wage. One professor in particular said if I thought I was going to go back to graduate school after working for a few years, I was in for a big surprise. My dad thinks the people with the best experience are those who waited to get their masters after working for a while.

Interested in going into industry afterwards. Also considering a PhD, but have been told by the same professor that PhDs are a waste of time.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Academia.SE!  Unfortunately, I'm not sure that strangers on the internet are going to be able to answer your question: there are good reasons to take either path, and which ones predominate strongly depends on the particulars of your personal skills, desires, and goals.

Comment: Nobody else can tell you what you **should** do.

Comment: It's time to stop conversing on these topics with Dr. Negative.  You may safely ignore everything he said.  If you are interested in studying, there's nothing to make anyone predict that you would not go back to school.  People do it all the time.

Answer (score 1):

Of the opinions you heard, most make sense to me. However the most important part is what **you want** to do. If you are eager to go into industry and want to try that, then go with that. If you prefer to do your graduate (and maybe later a PhD), then choose that. But do not plan too far ahead, i.e.: "I'll work 2 years, go to graduate school, do my PhD, and go back to industry." Real life does normally not work like that, and if you really are trying to reach these goals they might give you more stress and worries than help you.

I, after my master degree was kind of tired of University, and worked for a company during three years. After those three years I looked into different options (for personal and professional reasons), and decided to go back in research by doing a PhD.

Try to make a list of "pros and cons", and make a decision based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Graduate engineering programs often could be opted between two different directions. The working experience would affect both in different perspectives.

M.Eng is the program type, planned to prepare the students for successful participation within the industry. As a matter of fact, related working experience might strengthen the chance to be admitted into the program, because the committee would discern the applicant as a person with enough practical background, who can, potentially, deepen his/her skills by such program, better than the other people, without those set of experiences.

The second path, leads to the M.A.Sc. and would be completed with a Ph.D. degree. In this course, there are many Ph.D. positions, are which constructed based on the industrial projects (especially in european positions). Therefore, the corresponding position holders tend to recruit the applicants, are who familiar with the theme.

But, one could assert that postponing the graduate studies for gathering the working experience is not always a brilliant plan. Because, the aforementioned points within the previous paragraphs just augment your potential chance but not essential for tracking the target. You could pursue the graduate studies, deservedly, based on your solid scientific background and your bright resume.